# Draw a line on plotted surface if x=y using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

i am ploting a function K=f(x,y) and want to underline my statement by drawing lines onto the surface which fulfill x=y or x=2y. I tried using (if ? then: else) but have no clue how i can pass the else. I guess there is an easy solution but after all I am new to this and still have some trouble with pgf. Thanks for your help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{width=7.5cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={
Kd(\qb,\qd,\koa)  = {{\qd==\qb ? (\koa /((\koa / \qb )+1)) : (\qb *((exp(\koa /\qb *(1-(\qb /\qd)))-1)  /   (exp(\koa /\qb*(1-(\qb /\qd)))-(\qb /\qd))  )   )}};
},
]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.45\textwidth,
       height=6.5cm,
   % title={$k=f(KoA, QB, QD)$}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$QD$, zlabel=$K$,
    xtick={200, 300,400, 500},
        ytick={ 500,1000,1500},
             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.25cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.25cm},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%minor tick num=4,
          ]

\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=500:200,
    domain y=200:1500
] 
{ Kd(x,y,1000) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here you can see the surface where I would like to have some lines. How can do i get this image smaller?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Just add a parametric plot such as

```
\addplot3[color=blue,domain=500:200,samples y=0] (x,x,{Kd(x,x,1000)});
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{width=7.5cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,tight background,
declare function={Kd(\qb,\qd,\koa)=((\qd==\qb ? (\koa /((\koa / \qb )+1)) : 
(\qb *((exp(\koa /\qb*(1-(\qb /\qd)))-1)  / 
(exp(\koa /\qb*(1-(\qb /\qd)))-(\qb /\qd))))));}]
\begin{axis}[
width=0.45\textwidth,
       height=6.5cm,
   % title={$k=f(KoA, QB, QD)$}, 
    xlabel=$QB$, ylabel=$QD$, zlabel=$K$,
    xtick={200, 300,400, 500},
        ytick={ 500,1000,1500},
             zlabel style={yshift=-0.25cm}, 
     xlabel style={yshift=0.25cm},
          ylabel style={yshift=.25cm},
          x dir=reverse,
          grid=major,
%minor tick num=4,
          ]

\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=500:200,
    domain y=200:1500
] 
{ Kd(x,y,1000) };
\addplot3[color=blue,domain=500:200,samples y=0] (x,x,{Kd(x,x,1000)});
\addplot3[color=red,domain=250:200,samples y=0] (2*x,x,{Kd(2*x,x,1000)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Just another short question: how can i plot a surface where no values that fullfill the condition QB<QD are shown?

Comment: @94bb494nd41f You can use `nan`, see the example on p. 120 of pgplots manual v1.16. However, often the results obtained with `\clip` look better.